# Cannot move any element like textview/button in Android Studio 3.3.2

Tags: android-studio

I updated from Android Studio v3.1.2 to v3.3.2, updated everything successfully, backed up my projects and created a new project for test. But im not able to move any element/widget in Design tab. I was using RelativeLayout as i have used it in my older projects. In previous version, i was able to move freely in any layout but this looks like not working anymore.

Also i saw some solutions that switching to ConstraintLayout would help, i tried it and worked but i was more happy with RelativeLayout and the project i was working on uses RelativeLayout and this will take so much time to change it to ConstraintLayout manually. So is there any solution to work with RelativeLayout in the new version like once before.

Ok, this is the layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Here's a screenshot:
[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwnJi.png)

Comment: If you can, showing the code would be help us to find out the problem with layout

Comment: I have added the layout.xml, thanks for spending your time to help

Comment: May be, can you post screenshot and explain what you want to do with views. Not able to figure out problem with above code snippet

Comment: Ok i have provided screenshot and im not able to fix the item anywhere else, now can you provide any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
**By setting the top-bottom, left and right constraint help you to position the view on the layout relative to other views.**

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="184dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="343dp" android:layout_marginTop="369dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginStart="159dp"/>
```

take a look at this auto generated code also.

Comment: But shouldn't we have to set it everytime? If so I want those attributes to be already there? So how do I do that?

Comment: It's a bug, check here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129071672 because we didn't need to apply it with RelativeLayout rules on previous versions